# Spring Session - users sample not working with eclipse and tomcat 7

Tags: spring-session

I am trying to run the multiple users sample referred in the spring documentation https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/1.2.2.RELEASE//samples/users. However, I am facing an issue because it starts to look for a applicationContext.xml file. I dont understand why this happens when i am using a java-based approach to initialize the config(similar to the example). Below is the log snippet and the exception trace from eclipse concole:

`Sep 15, 2016 11:44:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
*INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [sample.Initializer@1465dd5]*
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Sep 15, 2016 11:44:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Sep 15, 2016 11:44:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
    ... 22 more
Sep 15, 2016 11:44:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 15, 2016 11:44:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/usersMultipleTab] startup failed due to previous errors`

EDIT:

I am Not sure if this info is required. But i am using Maven for dependency management.

EDIT:

Maven Config below(rest all is same from github):

```
            <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
              <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
              <groupId>SAMPLE</groupId>
              <artifactId>usersMultipleTab</artifactId>
              <packaging>war</packaging>
              <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
              <name>sample</name>
              <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
              <properties>
                    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
                    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                    <org.springframework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
                    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
                    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
              </properties>
              <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-ws</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.8</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>junit</groupId>
                      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                      <version>3.8.1</version>
                      <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                     <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                     <version>3.0.1</version>
                     <scope>provided</scope>
                   </dependency>
                   <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.15</version>
                    <exclusions> 
                        <exclusion> 
                         <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId> 
                         <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId> 
                        </exclusion> 
                         <exclusion> 
                          <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId> 
                           <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId> 
                         </exclusion> 
                         <exclusion>
                            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                      </exclusions>
                  </dependency>

                 <dependency>
                     <groupId>commons</groupId>
                     <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                     <version>1.2</version>
                </dependency>
                 <dependency>
                        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2</version>
                 </dependency>
                 <dependency>
                        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2</version>
                 </dependency>
                 <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
                        <version>4.1</version>
                </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
                            <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
                        </dependency>


              </dependencies>

            </project>
```

Comment: Are you trying to run the sample app from the Spring Session project itself or do you have your own project based on the sample app? If it's your own sample project (which reference to Maven makes me believe) please share it or at least provide relevant info about project and Spring Session configuration.

Comment: Barring the gradle configuration, I am using the exact same project from Spring-Session as in github. I am using Maven for dependency Management only.

Comment: The users sample from Spring Session project works for me. Can you share your sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Apologies for not replying these many days. I was busy with some Prod stuff. I have added my maven config.